# How do I prevent the video from zooming in/out in iOS with Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, video

I'm a beginner iOS Swift developer, and new to StackOverflow. I'm trying to develop my first game, and I wanted to use a video as an intro. I got the video playing and working properly, but a problem I am having is when I double tap the screen the video zooms in and out. Is there any way to prevent this?

Here is my code:

```
func playVideo() {

    if let
        path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("wakyIntro", ofType:"mp4"),
        url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path),
        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url) {
            self.moviePlayer = moviePlayer
            moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.bounds
            moviePlayer.prepareToPlay()
            moviePlayer.scalingMode = .AspectFill
            self.view.addSubview(moviePlayer.view)
            moviePlayer.fullscreen = true
            moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
            moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceType.File
            moviePlayer.play()
            println("Video loaded successfully")
    } else {
        debugPrintln("Ops, something wrong when playing the video")
    }
}
```

Then I call it from a separate ViewController that I use for my Main Menu

```
func mainMenuViewControllerDidPressVideo(mainMenuViewController: MainMenuViewController) {
    playVideo()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set **moviePlayer.view.userInteractionEnabled** to false.

```
moviePlayer.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

Or set controlStyle to Full Screen

```
moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen
```

Comment: Actually I fixed it by removing moviePlayer.fullscreen = true, and using your code above. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the user interaction. That will not cause the video to zoom in/out and it will ignore all user interaction in movie player view.

```
moviePlayer.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

Hope this helps.... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MPMoviePlayerViewController` instead of `MPMoviePlayerController`:

```
movieViewController = MPMoviePlayerViewController(contentURL: url)
movieViewController?.moviePlayer.fullscreen = true
movieViewController?.moviePlayer.controlStyle = .Embedded
moviePlayer.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
self.presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated(movieViewController)
```